# Angular2 and i18n implementation not displaying translated text

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have implemented i18n in a new angular2 project following the instructions in the official documentation.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html#!#i18n-attribute

The translation seems to work as there are no errors in console and if I remove the locale variable from index.html I see the default text. Also, inspecting under sources with Chrome dev tools, I can see the translation file has been loaded. However, no text gets displayed in the page for the translated fields.

I have also tried the implementation suggested here: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/4euRQQ?p=preview, using a ts file instead of the xlf file.

```
import { TRANSLATION } from './messages.fr';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,
  {
    providers: [
      { provide: TRANSLATIONS, useValue: TRANSLATION },
      { provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf' },
      { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr' }
    ]
  });
```

It gives the same result, no text in the page. I am using this in a different component , not directly in the app component template, does it make any difference? Do I have to import something into the custom component in order for it to work?

There are no errors in the console. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved this issue, the error was in the translation file syntax

Comment: What is the error in translation file?